# Unable to fetch the data from store.select when used combineReducers(reducers, initialState) using ngrx/store

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

This is the root reducer that I am injecting in `appmodule`:

```js
export const rootreducers = combinedReducers(reducers, initialState);
```

In appmodule

```js
StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, {
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE 
}),
```

`store.dispatch` works fine, but the moment I do:

```js
this.store.select(state => state.data).subscribe(y => y.url) // state is undefined
```

I did console.log of

```js
this.store.select(state => state.data);
```

below is the output:

```
ActionsSubject {
  closed: false,
  currentObservers: Array(1),
  observers: Array(1), 
  isStopped: false,
  hasError: false,
  …
}
reducerManager: ReducerManager {
  closed: false,
  currentObservers: null,
  observers: Array(1),
  isStopped: false,
  hasError: false,
  …
}
source: State {
  closed: false,
  currentObservers: null,
  observers: Array(3), 
  isStopped: false,
  hasError: false,
  …
}
```

Can you please tell me how to get the data from `store.select`? I see the data residing `ActionsSubject` ->_value.

Comment: try use `createSelector` from ngrx.